# How to create a csv file from List<String[]>

Tags: c#, linq, csv

Can anyone help me to create a csv file from List, my scenario is, i have a multi dimensional values like below in a List

```
List<string[]> lst = new List<string[]>();
lst= csv1.ToList();
```

lst contains the values like,

```
lst[0] = {string[53]}
lst[1] = {string[53]}
lst[2] = {string[53]}
lst[3] = {string[53]}
lst[4] = {string[53]}
```

and string[53] contains the values like

```
lst[0]
    string[0] = "abc"
    string[1] = "def"
    string[2] = "ghi"
    string[3] = "jkl"
    string[4] = "mno"
    ...
lst[1]
    string[0] = "123"
    string[1] = "456"
    string[2] = "789"
    string[3] = "10"
    string[4] = "11"
    ...
```

I just wanted to write this multi-dimensional list to csv file as each item in lst[] to rows in csv and each item in string[] to columns such that the final output in my csv is

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno
123,456,789,10,11
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I tried like this, String csv = String.Join(",", lst.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()); but i was not getting the output.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

At the simplest level, not handling quoting / escaping / multi-line CSV issues, then just loop; maybe something like:

```
    using (var file = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        foreach(var arr in lst)
        {
           file.WriteLine(string.Join(",", arr));
        }
    }
```

or a *tiny* bit more efficient (no intermediary string):

```
    using (var file = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        foreach (var arr in lst)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(arr)) continue;
            file.Write(arr[0]);
            for(int i = 1 ; i < arr.Length ; i++)
            {
                file.Write(',');
                file.Write(arr[i]);
            }
            file.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your second example is going to add an extra comma at the on each record

Answer (score 34):

use linq:

```
File.WriteAllLines("text.txt", lst.Select(x => string.Join(",", x)));
```

Comment: I am trying to do this will a "|" delimiter, and keeps producing a comma separated file, any idea as to why?

Comment: @jeffkenn in the string.Join() change the "," to "|"