# C# basics, read from files, make input via write line, save sort, Console application

Tags: c#

I've only been learning for a few weeks and I'm still at the beginning. To practice I wrote a small program that prompts for a score and a name, then compares it and gives feedback. see here:

```
static int highscore = 1000;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ///////////////////////////////////
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nDer aktuelle Highscor ist:   {0} \n\n ", highscore);


            Console.Write("\nBitte gib Deinen Score ein:\t");
            int score = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("\nBitte gib Deinen Namen  ein:\t");
            string spielerName = Console.ReadLine();


            string highscoreSpielerName;


            if (score <= highscore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nPech gehabt {0}, Du hast keinen neuen Highscore.", spielerName);

            }

            else if (score > highscore)
            {
                int newHigsore = highscore + score - 1000;
                int divHighscore = score - 1000;
                
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nHerzlichen Glückwunsch, der neue Highscore ist {0} Punkte !! ", newHigsore);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nDer alte Highscore war {0} Pnkte und wurde um {1} Punkte übertroffen.", highscore, divHighscore);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n{0} hät den neuen Highscore mit {1} Punkten !", spielerName, newHigsore);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
           
    }
```

Now I want to extend it as follows:
The input should be stored in a file (array,list), sorted by the highest score, then the following output should be made:

> You are among the top-ten, output whole list with ranking.

Or

> Bad luck, you have no new highscore.

Since I don't know much about arrays, saving and overwriting, I'm stuck here. Would be nice if you could help me here. This is my approach so far:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              String[] zeilen = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\visual Projekte\NeuDatenLesen\bin\Testdaten\Gewinner.CSV");

            foreach (string zeile in zeilen)
            {

                string[] daten = zeile.Split(';');
                double rang = double.Parse(daten[0]);
                string name = daten[1];
                double punkte = double.Parse(daten[2]);

                Console.WriteLine("Platz {0}\t{1}\tPunkte {2}", rang, name, punkte);

                Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Step 1: create  `class Score { public string Name { get; set; } ..}` and work with that for sorting and processing.  Makes the reading and writing an isolated part.

Comment: Examples on sorting can be found in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0

Comment: Writing a list of columns to a CSV - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815634/how-to-create-a-csv-file-from-liststring/13815673

Comment: Step 0: research those topics perhaps starting with some of the very good articles on S Docs.

Comment: @Henk Holterman   Thank you, I had already done that. Where I get stuck is first of all the question of how can I save the input that is retrieved via Console.Readline in the file?

Comment: When reading all scores from the file you use `ReadAllLines`. So would it not be obious that `WriteAllLines` will write to a file ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use objects.
Once objects are created, tools for Lists can be used.
Included here is a nugget for Newtonsoft.Json (used to serialize for file)
Also the use of Linq.

```
    public class Scores
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }
```

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ScoreList = new List<Scores>();
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Alpha", Score = 98324 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Bravo", Score = 88099 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Charlie", Score = 12012 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Delta", Score = 76590 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Echo", Score = 87199 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Foxtrot", Score = 99832 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Golf", Score = 20204 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Hotel", Score = 37209 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "India", Score = 08732 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Juliett", Score = 78782 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Kilo", Score = 99120 });
            ScoreList.Add(new Scores() { Name = "Lima", Score = 76555 });
            var saveScores = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ScoreList);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\work\Scores.json", saveScores);
            // read existin file
            var fileRead= File.ReadAllText(@"C:\work\Scores.json");

            List<Scores> existingScores = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Scores>>(fileRead);

            var highScores = existingScores.OrderByDescending(o => o.Score).Take(10).ToList();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. DeserializeObject and SerializeObject brings" Error CS1061 "object" does not contain a definition for "SerializeObject". using System.Text.Json; I have added. What can i do?